# How to find the values of a triangle matrix if it diagonalizable

Tags: diagonalization

If this matrix is diagonalizable then what are the values of $a_1$ through $a_6$?
$$\begin{bmatrix}
3&a_1&a_2&a_3\\
0&3&a_4&a_5\\
0&0&3&a_6\\
0&0&0&3
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I understand that the eigenvalues are $3$, but how do you solve for the variables?

Comment: the eigenspace will be a 4x4, because there are 4 eigenvalues which are all 3

Comment: When all else fails, actually diagonalize if you cannot figure out the Jordan Normal Form from the nice answer.

Comment: @jaredsmith: you've answered your own question by stating that the eigenspace of the only eigenvalue, $3$, has dimension $4$; note that this is equal to the multiplicity of the eigenvalue. This is equivalent to diagonalizability and so we are done.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Let $E_A(3)=\{v\in\mathbb{R}^4:Av=3v\}$ be the eigenspace relative to $3$ ($A$ is your matrix). What's the condition for diagonalizability? The dimension of $E_A(3)$ should be…

What's the algebraic multiplicity of the eigenvalue $3$? The characteristic polynomial is $(3-X)^n$ (guess what's $n$).

---

In this particular case, the problem is easier: the only diagonal matrix to which $A$ can be similar is
$$D=\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 3 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 3 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 3
\end{bmatrix}$$
Now, can you compute $SDS^{-1}$?

Comment: I guess I'm still confused, maybe you could expand on your hint

Comment: @jaredsmith Done, but you should remember the condition for diagonalizability.

Comment: the multiplicity is 4, and the condition is A=PDP^-1, but how does this help me know what the values of a1-a6?

Comment: yes, thank you1

Answer (score 0):

The characteristic polynomial is $(\lambda - 3)^4$, hence the only possible eingevalue is $3$. Therefore, over the basis which makes this matrix diagonal, there are only $3$'s on the diagonal. Conclude from this that $a_1 = \cdots = a_6 = 0$.

Hope that helps,